# searching an array deep inside a mongo document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

in my mongo collection called pixels, I have documents like the sample 
I'm looking for a way to search in the actions.tags part of the documents?

```
db.pixelsactifs.actions.find({tags:{$in : ["Environnement"]}})
db.pixelsactifs.find({actions.tags:{$in : {Environnement}})
```

doesn't work. I'm also looking for the PHP equivalent ?

I'm also asking myself should I make an "actions" collection instead of putting everything inside one document
I'm new to mongo so any good tutorial on structuring the db would be great

Thanks for the insight

```
{
  "_id": { $oid": "51b98009e4b075a9690bbc71" },
  "name": "open Atlas",
  "manager": "Tib Kat",
  "type": "Association",
  "logo": "",
  "description": "OPEN ATLAS",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Pixel Humain",
      "tags": [ "Toutes thémathiques" ],
      "description": "le PH agit localement",
      "images": [],
      "origine": "oui",
      "website": "www.echolocal.org"
    }
  ],
  "email": "my@gmail.com",
  "adress": "102 rue",
  "cp": "97421",
  "city": "Saint louis",
  "country": "Réunion",
  "phone": "06932"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
              collectionName->find(array("actions.tags" => array('$in' => "Environnement")));
```

I do not think you need to maintain the actions in separate collection. NoSQL gives you more flexibility to do embed th document . Event it allows sub document also be indexed . True power of NoSQL comes with merging the document into each other to get the faster retrieval. The only short coming I can see here , you can not get the part of sub document . find will always return the complete Parent document. In case you want to show one entry of subdocument array , it is not possible . It will return the whole subdocument and you have to filter in on the client side. So if you are planning to show action as individual to end user , it is better to have in separate collection

Read here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/

Comment: Additionally, if you're simply checking for one value in an array, you can do without `$in` and simply query on `["action.tags" => "Environnement"]`. [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) is going to be most useful if you're checking for multiple matches (functionally an "or" query). Inversely, the [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all) operator functions like an "and" query.